# Do I need to specify any particular settings for Boruta feature selection in regression problems?

Tags: r, feature-selection, boruta

I trying to solve a linear regression problem and would like to select the most important variables to use. I came across the `Boruta` package in R.

I am using it as follows:

```
important_feat <- Boruta(DepVar ~ IndepVar1 + IndepVar2 + IndepVar3, data=df)
```

where the `DepVar` is my continuous dependent variable that I want to estimate for the regression.

I would like to know if I am using Boruta correctly for feature selection in regression-based problems.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: @Tim yes, however, there was not much which explicitly provides this information.